# RegEx to remove all markup between <a and </a> tags except for within [ and ]

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

*Trying to figure out a Regular Expression gives me a brain cramp :)*

I'm replacing thousands of individual `href`links with an individual shortcode in WordPress post content using a plugin that allows me to run regular expressions on content.

Rather than try and combine an SQL query with a RegEx, I'm doing it in two stages: first the SQL to find/replace each individual URL to the individual shortcode, and the second stage, remove the rest of the 'href` link markup.

These are some examples of what I have now from the first step; as you can see, the URL has been replaced with the `[nggallery id=xxx]` shortcode.

```
<a href="[nggallery id=xx]"><span class="shutterset">
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-23067" title="Image Title" 
src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/image-title.jpg"
alt="" width="685" height="456" /></span></a>

<a href="[nggallery id=xxxxx]">Click here!</a>

<a title="title title" href="[nggallery id=xxx]" target="_blank">Title Link Title Link</a>
```

Now, I need to delete all the `href` link markup - `span`, `img`, etc - in between the leading `<a` and ending `</a>`, leaving just the shortcode `[nggallery id=xxx]`.

I've got a start here: **https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/2**

But I don't know how to prevent the `[nggallery id=xxx]` shortcode from being captured in the RegEx.

**Update 7/09/2015**

@nhahtdh's answer appears to work perfectly, is not too greedy, and doesn't eat adjacent html links. Use `(` and `)` as delimiters and `$1` as a replacement with a regex plugin in WordPress. (If using BBEdit, you will need to use `\1`)

```
( <a\s[^>]*"(\[nggallery[^\]]*\])".*?<\/a> )
```

**Update 7/02/2015**

Thanks to Fab Sa *(answer below)*, his regex at https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/4

```
<a.*(\[nggallery[^\]+]*\]).*?<\/a>
```

works in the regex101 emulator, but when used in the BBEdit text editor or the WordPress plugin that runs regex, his regex deletes the `[nggallery id=***]` shortcode. So is it too greedy? Some other issue?

**Update 7/01/2015:**

*I know, I know, re: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) YOU CANNOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX*

Comment: What are you executing the regex in? I'd capture the short code and just re-insert it on the replace. Maybe something like this https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/5 then `$1` will have your shortcodes. If you want the brackets move the parenthesis to the outside of those.

Comment: You can you [this](https://regex101.com/r/yW4mB0/2) regex and then replace the captured part. I think regex can be improved, but this works.

Comment: @vks, thanks but that still deletes the shortcode....

Comment: try `<a.*?(\[nggallery[^\]]*\]).*?<\/a>`

Comment: @markratledge you have to replace by `$1`.

Comment: @vks, but that gives me a literal `$1` instead of the shortcode in the resulting file, using BBedit.

Comment: Looks like BBEdit uses \1 instead of $1.  Does that work any better for you?

Comment: @PeterBrittain: thanks, that's it; BBEdit uses \1 But, the regex in comments above is still greedy and eats standalone links in between the ngg shorttags.

Comment: You're welcome.  I thought about the Regex briefly, but it looks like Nhahtdh has given you what you need...

Comment: What is the plugin that runs the regex? Does it allows you to use modifiers?

Comment: @AlexisN-o - Its PCRE. This is the link for BBEdit: https://gist.github.com/ccstone/5385334

Comment: @markratledge I wonder why nobody mentioned a solution based on a DOM parser. And I'm astonished that so many, even high ranked, users suggested the wrong thing: parsing HTML with regexes. Note that regexes are not the right tool to parse HTML. A DOM parser based solution would be the only reliable solution. Which language are you using? PHP?

Comment: @markratledge Too bad it does not seem to support the `U` modifier. BBEdit may have some limitations but it seems that you already have several correct answers. [Here is mine](https://www.regex101.com/r/jM1nG3/1) but you shouldn't use it because it is bad to use regex to parse html ;)

Comment: @Peter Brittain, thanks, and yes, nhahtdh's solution pretty much works.

Comment: @Alexis N-o, Thanks, I didn't reliize BBEdit used a different tegex engine. This is very iInteresting stuff once I got into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fab Sa's regex `<a.*(\[nggallery[^\]+]*\]).*?<\/a>` gobbles up everything when there are multiple `<a>` tags on a single line, due to the unrestricted `.*` at the beginning, which will match across different `<a>` tags.

By restricting the allowable characters, you can somewhat match what you want:

```
<a\s[^>]*"(\[nggallery[^\]]*\])".*?<\/a>
  ^^^^^^^
```

I forced at least one whitespace after `a` to make sure that it's not matching some other tags, plus some extra restrictions.

Anyway, you are on your own if you discover that it doesn't work in some corner case. It's generally a bad idea to manipulate HTML with regex.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that regex with html is very problematic. But, if I went with an html parser, I'd need to run some sort of php loop or ajax to access each WordPress post. Your regex still deletes the shortcode; but what 2 regexs, each run separately? One to strip html from the left of the shortcode, and then another to strip the right?

Comment: Ah, my mistake; this does work when running when using regex within Wordpress; but not in BBEdit. Maybe an incomplete implementation of regex in BBedit? Will test this different ways on the WordPress content. Thanks!

Comment: this appears to work perfectly, still need to test a few more instances. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use this regex

```
<a.*(\[nggallery[^\]+]*\]).*?<\/a>
```

globally (flag *g*). This regex will match a link and save the `[nggallery ...]` part. You can substitue the all match with $1 to keep the saved `[nggallery ...]` part.

I've updated your regex online: https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/4

PS: In this solution `[nggallery ...]` don't need to be in a specific attribut like *href*. If you want to force that, you can use `<a.*href\="(\[nggallery[^\]+]*\])".*?<\/a>`

Comment: You beat me to it! Also, a friendly reminder that [YOU CANNOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). However, this answer should be fine for your purposes

Comment: I agree. It's better to parse html with a real parser than regex but as you say, I've just reply and sometimes it's easier and/or quicker to regex.

Comment: Fab Sa and Zack, thanks! I've read YOU CANNOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX, but I figured I just wanted to delete markup. Problem is the regex works fine at regex101 but I get a "No ending matching delimiter '>'" found error when trying to run in my RegEx plugin to use with WordPress content. Does the regex need to be one line rather than having the $1 replace?

Comment: You should use delimiters like `/myregex/`. What your line of code looks like ?

Comment: I'd recommend using a delimiter not being used in your regex. If your delimiter is in your regex you need to escape it in every instance. Here's the PHP doc on the regex delimiters, not sure if you are using PHP or not, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php.

Comment: I'm using the regex as it works at regex101, with and without # for delimiters, but the regex seems to be greedy, as it deletes the shortcode as well. Existing shortcodes not in html markup are not deleted. I'm using the text editor BBEdit, which has full regex capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

True, you cannot parse html with regexs, how about making the behavior bulletproof with a minimalistic lexer-parser?
It would give you much more flexibility and control over your code.

```
<?php

$src = <<<EOF
<a href="[nggallery id=xx]"><span class="shutterset">
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-23067" title="Image Title" 
src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/image-title.jpg"
alt="" width="685" height="456" /></span></a>

<a href="[nggallery id=xxxxx]">Click here!</a>

<a title="title title" href="[nggallery id=xxx]" target="_blank">Title Link Title Link</a>
EOF;

// we "eat up" the source string by opening <a> tags, closing <a> tags or text
$tokens = array();
while ($src){
    // check if $src begins with this pattern <a (any optional prop)[nggallery (any string)] (any optional prop)>
    if (preg_match('/^<a [^>]*(\[nggallery [^\]]+\])[^>]*>/s', $src, $match)){
        // here you can handle data with more flexibility
        // you can grab the id or the [placeholder] via 
        //$match[1] = [nggallery id=xyz]

        // we store the chunk of string and label it as an opening tag
        $tokens[] = array('type' => 'OPENING_A', 'value' => $match[0]);
    }else if (preg_match('/^<\/a>/s', $src, $match)){
        // we store the chunk of string and label it as a closing tag
        $tokens[] = array('type' => 'CLOSING_A', 'value' => $match[0]);
    }else if (preg_match('/^./s', $src, $match)){
        // we store the chunk of string, in this case a character and label it as text
        $tokens[] = array('type' => 'TEXT', 'value' => $match[0]);
    }
    // finally we remove the identified pattern from the source string
    // and continue "eating it up"
    $src = substr($src, strlen($match[0]));
}

// once the source string has been consumed, we get this array
// var_dump($tokens);
// array (size=247)
//   0 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       'type' => string 'OPENING_A' (length=9)
//       'value' => string '<a href="[nggallery id=xx]">' (length=28)
//   1 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       'type' => string 'TEXT' (length=4)
//       'value' => string '<' (length=1)
//   2 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       'type' => string 'TEXT' (length=4)
//       'value' => string 's' (length=1)
//   3 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       'type' => string 'TEXT' (length=4)
//       'value' => string 'p' (length=1)
//       ... ommited for brevity


// now with all the parsed data, we can rebuild the html
// as needed
$html = '';
// we keep a flag to now if we are inside a tag
// marked with ngggallery
$insideNGGalleryTag = false;

foreach ($tokens as $token){
    if ($token['type'] == 'OPENING_A'){
        $insideNGGalleryTag = true;
        $html .= $token['value'];
    }else if ($token['type'] == 'CLOSING_A'){
        $insideNGGalleryTag = false;
        $html .= $token['value'];
    }else{
        // if we are inside a nggallery tag, we will ignore
        // all text inside it. here you could also remove
        // html properties from the tag, move the [nggallery placeholder]
        // inside the <a> or some other behavior you might need
        if (!$insideNGGalleryTag){
            $html .= $token['value'];
        }
    }
}

// finally echo or write to file the
// modified html, in this case it would return
var_dump($html);
// <a href="[nggallery id=xx]"></a>
// <a href="[nggallery id=xxxxx]"></a>
// <a title="title title" href="[nggallery id=xxx]" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, and I'll have to try it. I actaullly need to change content in WordPress posts, so I need to run regex or, if php, use an ajax routine to access the WordPress database without timing out

Answer (score 1):

```
/<a\b[^>]*href\s*=\s*"(\[nggallery id=[^"]+\])".*?<\/a>/i
```

That will put the short code `[nggallery id=XXX]` into group 1, then replace the match with the contents of group 1.

**NOTE:** this assumes reasonably well formatted HTML, the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to this but thought I'd throw this in the mix.
(Note- warning!! this may be hard to look at ..  )

*modified*: for BBEdit.
Note - BBEdit uses PCRE engine. BBEdit regex constructs can be found
here: https://gist.github.com/ccstone/5385334

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 # (?s)(<a(?=\s)(?>(?:(?<=\s)href\s*=\s*"\s*(\[nggallery\s+id\s*=\s*[^"\]>]*?\])"|".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>)(?<!/>)(?(2)|(?!))).*?</a\s*>

 (?s)
 (                             # (1 start), Capture open a tag
      <a                            # Open a tag
      (?= \s )
      (?>                           # Atomic
           (?:
                (?<= \s )
                href \s* = \s*                # href attribute
                "
                \s* 
                (                             # (2 start), Capture shortcode value
                     \[nggallery \s+ 
                     id \s* = \s* [^"\]>]*? 
                     \]
                )                             # (2 end)
                "
             |  " .*? "
             |  ' .*? '
             |  [^>]*? 
           )+
           >
      )
      (?<! /> )                     # Not a self contained closure
      (?(2)                         # Only a tags with href attr, shortcode value
        |  (?!)
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 .*?                           # Stuff inbetween
 </a \s* >                     # Close a tag
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 240 ) 
<a href="[nggallery id=xx]"><span class="shutterset">
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-23067" title="Image Title" 
src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/image-title.jpg"
alt="" width="685" height="456" /></span></a>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 28 ) 
<a href="[nggallery id=xx]">  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 9 , len 17 ) 
[nggallery id=xx]  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 244 , len 46 ) 
<a href="[nggallery id=xxxxx]">Click here!</a>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 244 , len 31 ) 
<a href="[nggallery id=xxxxx]">  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 253 , len 20 ) 
[nggallery id=xxxxx]  
-----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 294 , len 90 ) 
<a title="title title" href="[nggallery id=xxx]" target="_blank">Title Link Title Link</a>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 294 , len 65 ) 
<a title="title title" href="[nggallery id=xxx]" target="_blank">  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 323 , len 18 ) 
[nggallery id=xxx]
```

Comment: @sin, thanks, this is very interesting and very different looking. This is a difficult thing to do. Both these regexs for some reason crash my editor BBEdit. Seems like there is a loop created and BBEdit freezes up after it warns me that is finding/replacing....

Comment: @markratledge - Indeed, that was wrong. Changed the regex for BBEdit. I think this one works now. Anyway, try it out.

Comment: @markratledge - Hey, no problem. The regex may look complex, but there is safety features built into it that simple expressions can't account for that handles possible ill-formed html, but still knows the correct end bracket. It's modifiable and, fast as lightning, fwiw. Normally, the valid tag would be parsed, then attr/vals regex sub-parses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that matches perfectly against your examples.

`(<a.*?href=")|([^\]]*?<\/a>)`

Instead of trying to match the entire expression at once, I used the OR operator to specify two separate regexes, one for the start of the `a` tag, `<a.*?href="` and one for the end of the a tag `[^\]]*?<\/a>`.  This may or may not work in a single replace operation, if not, split it into two replace operations, first run the one for the end-tag regex, then run the one for the start-tag.  Let me know if you have any additional examples that break this answer.

Comment: I have to point out that I have made the assumption that `]` will not be found anywhere else inside the `a` tag.  If the presence of that character there is a possibility, then this regex would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do this using regex, when it can be done using JavaScript DOM manipulations.

I will show you the basic way, to give you an idea:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = yourString;
var a = div.querySelector('a');
document.body.innerHTML = a.attributes[0].nodeValue;
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh9ttxxa/)**

Also check [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Comment: thanks, this is possible, but I need to write to the database and save changes, as the content is in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified, I am assuming that there are no nested anchor tags, and you simply want to extract the square bracketed code that is in there.  I am also assuming that the identifying format of your code is "[nggallery".

Find using this

```
<\s*a(?=\s|>)[^>]*?(\[nggallery[^\]]+\])[^>]*>(.|\n)+?(<\s*\/\s*a\s*>)
```

REPLACE using

```
\1
```

(which should be the first captured group notation for BBEdit)

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

`(?<=nggallery\sid=xx]">).*(?=<\/a>)`

Use global and single-line as modifiers (-g and -s). This matches everything between `<a href="[nggallery id=xx]">` and `</a>`. I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly or not... but this RegEx does what I just described.

Comment: It's not what he asked. With the flag *s* it will keep one line and you dont save the nggallery part + check the other answer.

Comment: Is there a reason your RegEx doesn't match the first `<a href="[nggallery id=xx]">` ( line 1 ). In my RegEx101 engine, it's not showing that yours matches that one, which seems like a bug to me.

Comment: great! nice work. I don't know why my engine was only matching the last two with your RegEx, but it works now. Strange...